# Scroll height no funciona cuando debe de disminuir

Tags: javascript

Lo que quiero hacer es que con base en el número de líneas en el textarea se modifique el tamaño del mismo, logro hacer esto cuando tiene que aumentar pero no cuando quiero que disminuya.

```js
function setHeigth() {
  let cuda = document.getElementById('cuda');
  let cudaContent = cuda.value.split('\n');
  let cudaLength = cudaContent.length;
  let cudaScroll = cuda.scrollHeight;

  if (cudaLength > 4) {
    document.getElementById('cuda').style.height = cudaScroll + 'px';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('cuda').style.height = '50px';
  }
}

setInterval('setHeigth()', 100);
```

```html
<textarea id='cuda'>
</textarea>
```

Supongo que es algún error muy tonto, igualmente gracias de antemano.

Comment: La cantidad de líneas no debería calcularse así, debería intervenir el height del textarea entre el line-height para realizar el calculo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya quedó :)